# Finding matching list item index number c#

Tags: c#, list

I am using .net 2.0  and i try to find the index of a given list. The list is a bit longer but i show it below in a shoter version. I wrote various variation of below code but it doesn't work, although i think i am close to a solution, i am just missing it.

```
  List<string> arrayLanguages =  new List<string> {"EN","NL","DE"};

  int Languagenr = arrayLanguages.Find(item => item.Equals ("DE"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexOf should give you the position

Try this:

```
int pos = arrayLanguages.IndexOf("EN");
```

Answer (score 3):

IndexOf() is what you're looking for!

```
List<string> arrayLanguages = new List<string> { "EN", "NL", "DE" };

int Languagenr = arrayLanguages.IndexOf("DE");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `IndexOf()` function that is inbuilt into List which returns the index value of what you are looking for.

input:

```
List<string> arrayLanguages = new List<string> { "EN", "NL", "DE" };
int index = arrayLanguages.IndexOf("DE");
```

output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `List<T>.FindIndex()` `Method`

```
List<string> arrayLanguages = new List<string> { "EN", "NL", "DE" };

int Languagenr = arrayLanguages.FindIndex(x=> x== "DE");
```

`Returns Index of 2`